# elasticsearch-head can't connection to elasticsearch with http://localhost:9200

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-head

elasticsearch version : elasticsearch-5.2.0

elasticsearch-head version : latest version

Start service successfully：

```
#### node1 ####
deMacBook-Pro:bin yyq$ ./elasticsearch
[2017-02-15T13:08:57,174][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] initializing ...
[2017-02-15T13:08:57,303][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [yml-es-node-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/disk1)]], net usable_space [21.4gb], net total_space [232.6gb], spins? [unknown], types [hfs]
[2017-02-15T13:08:57,304][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [yml-es-node-1] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-02-15T13:08:57,355][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] node name [yml-es-node-1], node ID [hqVAcDOdRu-LXuAgUEX9oQ]
[2017-02-15T13:08:57,358][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] version[5.2.0], pid[93922], build[24e05b9/2017-01-24T19:52:35.800Z], OS[Mac OS X/10.11.6/x86_64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_25/25.25-b02]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,802][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,803][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,803][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,803][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,803][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,803][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,803][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,804][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,804][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,804][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-02-15T13:08:58,805][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] no plugins loaded
[2017-02-15T13:09:02,610][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] initialized
[2017-02-15T13:09:02,610][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] starting ...
[2017-02-15T13:09:02,953][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [yml-es-node-1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9300}, {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-02-15T13:09:06,125][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [yml-es-node-1] detected_master {yml-es-node-2}{FWhiCkI7TV6hJOlmT_fgQg}{URIaxsK2T0aP7jRRe6TDfg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9301}, added {{yml-es-node-2}{FWhiCkI7TV6hJOlmT_fgQg}{URIaxsK2T0aP7jRRe6TDfg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9301},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [master {yml-es-node-2}{FWhiCkI7TV6hJOlmT_fgQg}{URIaxsK2T0aP7jRRe6TDfg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9301} committed version [385]])
[2017-02-15T13:09:06,175][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [yml-es-node-1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9200}, {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2017-02-15T13:09:06,175][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] started

#### node2 ####
deMacBook-Pro:bin yyq$ ./elasticsearch
[2017-02-15T10:31:03,936][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-2] initializing ...
[2017-02-15T10:31:04,087][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [yml-es-node-2] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/disk1)]], net usable_space [19.3gb], net total_space [232.6gb], spins? [unknown], types [hfs]
[2017-02-15T10:31:04,087][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [yml-es-node-2] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-02-15T10:31:04,104][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-2] node name [yml-es-node-2], node ID [FWhiCkI7TV6hJOlmT_fgQg]
[2017-02-15T10:31:04,112][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-2] version[5.2.0], pid[85158], build[24e05b9/2017-01-24T19:52:35.800Z], OS[Mac OS X/10.11.6/x86_64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_25/25.25-b02]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-02-15T10:31:05,832][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-2] no plugins loaded
[2017-02-15T10:31:09,871][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-2] initialized
[2017-02-15T10:31:09,871][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-2] starting ...
[2017-02-15T10:31:10,171][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [yml-es-node-2] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9301}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9301}, {[::1]:9301}, {127.0.0.1:9301}
[2017-02-15T10:31:13,327][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [yml-es-node-2] detected_master {yml-es-node-1}{hqVAcDOdRu-LXuAgUEX9oQ}{VrY6MUvhQNetUmbzcRnKMg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, added {{yml-es-node-1}{hqVAcDOdRu-LXuAgUEX9oQ}{VrY6MUvhQNetUmbzcRnKMg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [master {yml-es-node-1}{hqVAcDOdRu-LXuAgUEX9oQ}{VrY6MUvhQNetUmbzcRnKMg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300} committed version [223]])
[2017-02-15T10:31:13,388][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [yml-es-node-2] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9201}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9201}, {[::1]:9201}, {127.0.0.1:9201}
[2017-02-15T10:31:13,388][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-2] started

deMacBook-Pro:elasticsearch-head-master yyq$ grunt server
Running "connect:server" (connect) task
Waiting forever...
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9100
```

When I opened the url：http://localhost:9100 and clicked [connect] button, but I'm unable to connect to `elasticsearch`.
Could anyone help me?
This is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i86d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration, you probably have the following setting:

```
http.port: 9201
```

This is also visible in your logs:

```
[...] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9201}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9201}, {[::1]:9201}, {127.0.0.1:9201}
                                  ^
                                  |
                            your HTTP port
```

So in your `elasticsearch-head` interface, you need to connect to `localhost:9201` not `localhost:9200`.

**UPDATE**

You also need to add `http.cors.enabled: true` in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration and restart your ES server

Comment: In my computer, there are two instance，[yml-es-node-1]'s port is 9200,[yml-es-node-2]'s port is 9201. when i changed to http://localhost:9201, also can't connection.

Comment: Is yml-es-node-1 running?

Comment: If you open the Developer console of your browser, what do you see in the Network pane?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health. Origin http://localhost:9100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Then you need to add `http.cors.enabled: true` in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration and restart your ES server

Comment: thanks for your reminding，when i setting ［http.cors.enabled: true］ and ［http.cors.allow-origin: /http?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/］ in my elasticsearch.yml, and restart service, i can access the http://localhost:9200. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous post, to be able to run the head plugin to check the health status of the ElastiSearch cluster, you need to enable the CORS's environmental variables. One way is to mount the config file for ES as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002643/how-to-use-the-official-docker-elasticsearch-container).  Alternatively, you can define the environmental variables directly in your *docker-compose* as documented in [this](https://github.com/appbaseio/dejavu/issues/256) GitHub issue. I am adding the code below for completeness, which worked for me:

```
version: '3'
services:
    # search engine
    elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.0.1
        container_name: elasticsearch
        environment:
            - discovery.type=single-node
            - http.port=9200
            - http.cors.enabled=true
            - http.cors.allow-origin=http://localhost:1358,http://127.0.0.1:1358
            - http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization
            - http.cors.allow-credentials=true
            - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
            - 'ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
        ports:
            - '9200:9200'
            - '9300:9300'
    # elasticsearch browser
    dejavu:
        image: appbaseio/dejavu:3.2.3
        container_name: dejavu
        ports:
            - '1358:1358'
        links:
            - elasticsearch
```

**Note** that using `- http.cors.allow-origin=*` works and it could be handy for certain development setups.