# How to use the official docker elasticsearch container?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, elasticsearch-plugin

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0
RUN elasticsearch
EXPOSE 80
```

I think the 3rd line is never reached.

When I try to access the dockercontainer from my local machine through: 
172.17.0.2:9300

I get nothing, what am I missing? I want to access elasticsearch from the local host machine.

Comment: you should read https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/ the part Running Containers

Comment: that one is deprecated, have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-configuration-methods) instead

Comment: @user2915097, So I run ` docker run -d elasticsearch`and after going to 172.17.0.2:9300 I still don't get any output

Comment: are you using Linux, Mac or Windows?

Comment: expose ports `9200,9300` as per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_notes_for_production_use_and_defaults)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I recommend using docker-compose (which makes lot of things much easier) with following configuration.

## Configuration (for development)

Configuration starts 3 services: elastic itself and extra utilities
for development like kibana and head plugin (these could be omitted,  if you don't  need   them).

In the same directory you will need three files:

- docker-compose.yml
- elasticsearch.yml
- kibana.yml

With following contents:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0
    container_name: elasticsearch_540
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    mem_limit: 2g
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.4.0
    container_name: kibana_540
    environment:
      - SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
  headPlugin:
    image: mobz/elasticsearch-head:5
    container_name: head_540
    ports:
      - 9100:9100

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local
```

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
cluster.name: "chimeo-docker-cluster"
node.name: "chimeo-docker-single-node"
network.host: 0.0.0.0

http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-headers: "Authorization"
```

**kibana.yml**

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
elasticsearch.username: elastic
elasticsearch.password: changeme
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
```

## Running

With above three files in the same directory and that directory set as current working directory you do (could require sudo, depends how you have your docker-compose set up):

```
docker-compose up
```

It will start up and you will see logs from three different services:  `elasticsearch_540`, `kibana_540` and `head_540`.

After initial start up you will have your elastic cluster available for http under **9200** and for tcp under **9300**. Validate with following curl if the cluster started up:

```
curl -u elastic:changeme http://localhost:9200/_cat/health
```

Then you can view and play with your cluster using either kibana (with credentials elastic / changeme):

```
http://localhost:5601/
```

or head plugin:

```
http://localhost:9100/?base_uri=http://localhost:9200&auth_user=elastic&auth_password=changeme
```

Comment: many thanks slawek for writting such a complete guide, I'll try to make it run later

Comment: Thanks(& sorry for late answer) it is working at `http://localhost:9100/` so If I wanted to put some info inside the elastic search container how do I proceed for that, any pointers appreciated

Comment: I recommend starting [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/_exploring_your_cluster.html). Just keep in mind that all the REST calls will have to be run similar to health check `curl -u elastic:changeme http://localhost:9200/_cat/health` with credentials and on port 9200 (if you didn't change the defaults). So creating an index would be `curl -u elastic:changeme -XPUT http://localhost:9200/customer` and indexing document `curl -u elastic:changeme -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "name": "John Doe" }'`.

Comment: The Elastic search node doesn't show up when using Head plugin. I can see it from Kibana though. Also in case I want to add multiple nodes to the cluster should I just replicate the elasticsearch service in docker compose?

Comment: Weird. Are you sure you didn't change the default password? Or the `http.cors` settings from elasticsearch.yml? Maybe mobz/elasticsearch-head:5 has changed in the meantime. Not sure, cause on my machine the compose still works. As for multi node setup I have not played with it but there is a example setup in elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html). So something similar should work. They are using unicast to point second node to the first one.

Comment: It may be silly but... am i right that the only purose of the `head_540` is to provide some GUI for the elastic search?

Comment: Yes you're correct. Head plugin is just for convenience, for people used to having it available in previous elastic versions. It is just a web page GUI for managing indices. Similar could be told about kibana. They are not required, just useful to graphically see that things are working. In fact I'm using [cerbero](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro) more often than head these days.

Comment: Thank you! I tried with enviromentvariables in the composer-file but I couldnt get it working. But with your help its working :)

Answer (score 3):

Your container is auto exiting because of insufficient virtual memory, by default to run an elastic search container your memory should be a min of `262144` but if you run this command `sysctl vm.max_map_count`and see it will be around 65530. Please increase your virtual memory count by using this command `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` and run the container again `docker run IMAGE ID`then you should have your container running and you should be able to access elastic search at port 9200 or 9300

edit : check this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/vm-max-map-count.html#vm-max-map-count

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to follow the official elasticsearch documentation which has a nice section on [single node elasticsearch cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-dev-mode) Also running a [multi-node elasticsearch cluster using docker-compose](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file).

Please refer to version specific documentation, which can be accessed in the version drop-down present in elasticsearch official documentation.