# where is my elasticsearch.yml in my docker image

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, containers

I have a `docker` container that's running `elasticsearch` `v6.0.` I want to modify my `elasticsearch.yml` so that I can set the `path.repos` so I can add a directory to use for my `snapshot` and `restore` that I want to do my `index` before I make changes to it. I don't see the `elasticsearch.yml` in my docker container and not able to find it. Can someone point me to where I can find it? If it's not on the container itself, what steps can I take to add one to the container so that I can snapshot and restore my index? Thanks.

Comment: here /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ inside the container

Comment: Thank you I will post your answer and tag you!

Comment: simple google search would have told you that :) , also this great question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002643/how-to-use-the-official-docker-elasticsearch-container

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @Lupanoide I was able to find where the `elasticsearch.yml` file is on my container. It is located in the `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config`. Thank you @Lupanoide for your answer. You can also see his comment above!

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu docker container using Elasticsearch v7.10, the location is

- Configs: `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`
- Executable: `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin`
- Logs: `/var/log/elasticsearch`
- Data: `/var/lib/elasticsearch`
- Start service: `service elasticsearch start`

See more at [Configuring Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/settings.html#config-files-location)