# Elasticsearch and kibana docker images are not working properly

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I followed the accepted answer here [How to use the official docker elasticsearch container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002643/how-to-use-the-official-docker-elasticsearch-container)

but the **kibana UI is not coming up in the browser localhost:5601**, **what could be the problem?**

```
 [root@localhost ~]# sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
    vm.max_map_count = 262144

 [root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
 262144
 [root@localhost ~]#
```

**error log: docker-compose up**

```
kibana       | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-28T02:09:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
kibana      | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-28T02:09:55Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
kibana      | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-28T02:09:55Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
```

**docker ps :**

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
b978841f86d5        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1   "/bin/bash bin/es-do…"   14 minutes ago      Up 31 seconds       0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   elasticsearch
9f255a223659        docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.1                "/bin/sh -c /usr/loc…"   14 minutes ago      Up 31 seconds       0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp                           kibana
c21d1a77f25f        mobz/elasticsearch-head:5                             "/bin/sh -c 'grunt s…"   14 minutes ago      Up 31 seconds       0.0.0.0:9100->9100/tcp                           head
```

**OS: Centos 7**

**docker: latest**

**docker-compose: latest**

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.6.1
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch 
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    networks:
      - elastic

network:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

[final capture here after adding the network part (suggested by @Nagle Zhang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieaE3.png)

[On GCP ubuntu 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu52O.png)

Answer (score 0):

by the command `docker ps` , we can tell your service (kibana&es) both worked currectly.

the **true problem is you Kibana service can not find Elasticsearch service** , because it **can not resolve the address http://elasticsearch:9200**.

can you share your docker-compose file? I assume it's because of your network in docker-compose is incurrect.

1. run `docker exec -it kibana bash`
2. ping elasticsearch , check if it's working.
3. exit kibana container , run command `docker inspect kibana` `docker inspect elasticsearch` to check if both in a same network.
4. if it's not, please change the network to code below.

add a network for your container.

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.6.1
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch 
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    networks:
      - elastic

network:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I edited the question, pls check the docker compose file, the same docker can run well on another ubuntu pc but not on centos, I wonder why. I tried all the possible solutions

Comment: Is elasticsearch running up successfully?

Comment: it's really wired, why you named your container name is elasticsearch & kibana, but your really name is kibana_540 & elasticsearch_540

Comment: seems it works , you can tell by `docker ps` , the ealsticsearch status is `up 31 seconds`

Comment: everything is working fine but kibana cannot connect to ES, @ Nagle Zhang the dockercompose-file.yml is for another attempt, I just changed the name to see if it would work

Comment: I think you can change `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` from `http://elasticsearch:9200` to `http://elasticsearch_540:9200` temporarily solve the problem. but we need to find out why centos change your container from elasticsearch to elasticsearch_540

Comment: @Nagle Zhang the container name should match with the URL so if I change the URL name I have to change the container name as well

Comment: yeah, now the problem is the URL not match the container_name. 
```container_name: elasticsearch_540 
URL: http://elasticsearch:9200```

Comment: Centos didn't change the image name, the browser is showing `kibana service not ready yet`

Comment: yes, image name didn't chanted , container name is not currect.  run `docker ps`, the last column (NAME) is `elasticsearch_540` which is incurrect. can you check it?

Comment: I just checked again it elasticsearch and kibana [NAME]

Comment: I edited everything as I am getting it right now, nothing is working

Comment: sorry to hear that. please try my new post. see if can helps.

Comment: I tried now it's saying `elasticsearch    | [2020-05-28T06:11:46,893][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.s.m.NativeRoleMappingStore] [es01] Failed to clear cache for realms [[]]
`

Comment: can you access kibana now ?  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/35218

Comment: no only Elastic search, pls check the image link I added

Comment: the same docker-compose.yml file was running successfully 3 months earlier on ubuntu 16.04, even now I trie, it's still working but not on centos, and I also copied the suggested solution on ubuntu the same error is showing. can you try on your PC or GCP?

Comment: but this works on my windows 10. so sorry for this, it's too wired, I'm willing to help. but seems unable to do so.

Comment: by the log, seems elasticsearch is in red status, you can check by running `curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/health`. can you check why? seems now it's a new problem.

Comment: `curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/health`
`1590648183 06:43:03 docker-cluster green 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 - 100.0%`

Comment: I just tried it on GCP using ubuntu 16.04, still getting the same error, check the capture

Comment: It's working on windows now, sometimes it works and doesn't work on some Linux distros, I didn't change anything tho. What could be the problem? I think there could be other issues that are not linked to the images, better find out.

Comment: yeah, seems the main reason is beacuse the network(can not resovle) not working , maybe you can check in this way. for example , check /etc/resolve.conf etc.

Comment: I don't think it's an error related to the docker network because the same code runs elsewhere. maybe the firewall or any other reasons. anyway let's close this. thx @Nagle Zhang